# How to make launch icon to behave as a folder?

Tags: android, deep-linking, launching-application

I want my app launch icon to behave as a folder and show icons for deep links in the app as folder contents when clicked on the icon. Can I do without help from the launcher?

I understand I can have multiple app launch icons, but can they by default be grouped into a folder?

And this will sound hilarious, but if the above is possible, is there any way to make it dynamic?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the [app shortcut API](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts)? It allows you to add a dynamic set of shortcuts deep linking into your app that are available from the launcher.

Comment: App shortcut API the one with long press and options showing up is a fairly different behaviour than what I need.